# Cout and Hex [C++]

Tags: c++

Why when you write std::cout twice it shows the hexadecimal value and then what you wanted to output?

E.g.

```
std::cout << std::cout << "Hello!";
```

Comment: Perhaps you are getting the pointer value of `cout` and then the "Hello!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::ostream` has a conversion operator that allows conversion to `void*` so you can test if operation was successful. In expression

```
std::cout << std::cout  // similar to 
                        // std::cout.operator<<( std::cout.operator  void*())
```

the right-hand operand expression `std::cout` is implicitly converted to `void const*` using this conversion operator and then the `operator<<` [does the output of this via the ostream operand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) . Another way to see this is:

```
const void* cp = std::cout.operator  void*();
std::cout << cp << "Hello!" << std::endl;
std::cout << std::cout << "Hello!";
```

output:

0x601088Hello!

0x601088Hello!

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` has a type `std::ostream` (or something derived from
it).  There is no `<<` which takes this type on the right, so
the compiler looks for a conversion.  In pre-C++11,
`std::ostream` converts implicitly to `void*` (for use in
conditionals), so the compiler uses this; what you're seeing is
the output of what the conversion operator returns (typically,
the address of the `std::ostream` object itself, but all that is
required is that it be a non-null pointer).